# set expire date in facebook login

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

About the FB sdk. Wich parameter I could use to set the session expire date?

I got this error

> Error validating access token: Session has expired on Wednesday, 25-May-16 10:00:00 PDT. The current time is Friday, 27-May-16 02:19:23 PDT

My login code is like this :

```
FB.login(function (response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        // user just authorized your app
    }
}, {
    scope: 'public_profile,user_friends,email',
    return_scopes: true
});
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can´t set the expiration date on your own. A User Token is valid for 2 hours. An Extended User token is valid for 60 days.

More information about Tokens and how to generate them:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

In general, you don´t need to worry about Tokens when using the JS SDK.

Comment: Thanks it's helping :)

Comment: you are welcome. please don´t forget to accept my answer ;)